# Was the other Ballerina a sparrow too?

Tags: red-sparrow

Uncle Vanya in *Red Sparrow* is a manipulator. And I was under the impression he always wanted to have some "action" with Dominika. 
That's clearly why he prostitutes her through the sparrow program.

That was quite lucky for him that not only did the correct circumstances happen that he can ultimately blackmail her into the sparrows. 
But more 'luck' was the fact that he happened to be able to tap that one phone conversation to change Dominika's spirit, and give her a taste for blood.

But was it luck?
The accident that cost Dominika her dancing career, that started all the movie's events, was caused basically because the dancer had sex with the second ballerina, and that the ballerina was able to convince him to assault Dominika. 
That needed some kind of persuasion. Not just a pretty face and soft body (I don't imagine the first dancer at the Bolshoï having difficulties finding willing pretty women).

Placing a spy at the Bloshoi is some hard work, but I can see it bear result long term (at least as long as you don't sacrifice her hoping to shag your nephew), After all the first assignment of Dominika was because she was a dancer.

Do we have any clues (inworld or outworld) that the second ballerina was indeed a sparrow and that she acted at the explicit demand of Vanya?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## No, she was not.

The novel makes it clear that this was an act of jealousy by the other ballerina and that the "accident" was, in fact, no such thing.

> At twenty-two, Sonya Moroyeva probably had one final year to move up from the academy to the Bolshoi, but with Egorova in the running that year, her chances were not good. She had been dancing all her life, was the daughter of a full member of the Duma, and was at the core a spoiled and vain young woman. She was, frankly, desperate. She had been recklessly sleeping with a boy in the troupe, blond, lynx-eyed Konstantin, an incredibly risky activity that if discovered by the instructors would have guaranteed their instant dismissal from the school. But after fifteen years in the academy she knew the quiet times, and when the sauna room was deserted, and how long they had for their sweaty sessions, with her supple legs bent over her head, and she whispered in Konstantin’s ear for a week, and told him she loved him, and ground her hips up at him, licking the sweat from his face, and begged him to save her career, her life.
>
> Experienced ballet students know as much about anatomy and joints and injuries as a doctor. Konstantin, rabbit-mad in his gluttony for Sonya’s pizda, waited until he was paired with Dominika. Practicing a pas de deux on a crowded floor, he stepped hard on her heel when she was en pointe, forcing her foot forward, and the colors bled and her world went swirling black, and she buckled to searing pain and total collapse.